# Commodity Futures Hierarchical Data Structure

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-data, trading, algorithmic-trading

I for the life of me cant seem to get the structure I want and have it function properly, so in a fit of rage I come to you guys.

Setup:
I have a Directory called Futures_Contracts and inside is about 30 folders all named with the underlying asset, and finally inside the 6 nearest expiration contracts in csv format. Each csv is identical in format and contains Date,O,H,L,C,V,OI,Expiration Month.

Note: O H L C V OI is open, high, low, close, volume, open interest (for those not familiar) also assume close is synonymous with settlement below

## [image: Folder Structure]

Task: From here the goal is to load in the futures data into a multi-index pandas dataframe in such a way that the top-level index is the underlying commodity symbol, the mid-level index is the expiration Month-Year, and finally the OHLC data. The end goal is to have something that I can start hacking at the zipline module to get it running on futures.
So visually:
[image]

My Feeble attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import datetime
plt.figsize(16,8)

deliveries = {}
commoidities = {}
columns = 'open', 'high', 'low', 'settle', 'volume', 'interest', 'delivery' #Contract fields
path = os.getcwdu()+'/Futures_Contracts/' #Futures Path
for sym in os.listdir(path):
    if sym[0] != '.': #Weed out hidden files
        deliveries[sym] = []
        i = 0
        for contract in os.listdir(path + sym):
            temp = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(path + sym + '/' + contract, index_col=0, parse_dates = True, names = columns)#pull in the csv
            deliveries[sym].append(str(contract[:-4][-1] + contract[:-4][:-1][-2:])) #add contract to dict in form of MonthCode-YY
            commodities[sym] = deliveries[sym]
            commodities[sym][i] = temp
            i += 1
```

This somewhat works, however this is really a nested dict that holds a dataframe at the end. Therefore slicing is extremely clunky:

```
commodities['SB2'][0]['settle'].plot()
commodities['SB2'][3]['settle'].plot()
commodities['SB2'][4]['settle'].plot()
commodities['SB2'][3]['settle'].plot()
commodities['SB2'][4]['settle'].plot()
commodities['SB2'][5]['settle'].plot()
```

and yields [image]

Optimally I will be able to slice across each of the indexes so that I can compare data across assets, expiration, date and value. Furthermore label what I am looking at, as you can see in the matplotlib chart everything is simply named 'settle'

There is surely a way to do this, but I am just not smart enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going to be much better off getting this into one DataFrame, so consider using a MultiIndex. Here's a toy example, which I think will translate well to your code:

```
In [11]: dfN13 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]], columns=[['N13', 'N13'], ['a', 'b']])

In [12]: dfM13 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4]], columns=[['M13', 'M13'], ['a', 'b']])
```

*These are the DataFrames in your example, but the column's first level it just the asset name.*

```
In [13]: df = pd.concat([dfN13, dfM13], axis=1)

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   N13     M13
     a  b    a  b
0    1  2    3  4
```

For convenience we can label the columns-levels and index.

```
In [15]: df.columns.names = ['asset', 'chart']

In [16]: df.index.names = ['date']  # well, not in this toy example

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
asset  N13     M13
chart    a  b    a  b
date
0        1  2    3  4
```

*Note: This looks quite like your spreadsheet.*

And we can grab out a specific chart (e.g. ohlc) using `xs`:

```
In [18]: df.xs('a', level='chart', axis=1)
Out[18]:
asset  N13  M13
date
0        1    3

In [19]: df.xs('a', level='chart', axis=1).plot()  # win
```

Comment: Please allow me to pick your brain a little more. Unfortunately not all of the underlying assets have identical contract expirations. How can I handle this? I am thinking creating a dataframe isn't going to be viable for this reason. Optimally their is a trick in joining the csv's together, any thoughts?

Comment: Yes different dates, but I am concerned about the columns that correspond to an explicit expiration.

Comment: For instance N13 corresponds to a contract expiring in July 2013. In your example you used the contracts N13, and M13. For illustration I am going to add an additional contract Z13, and another underlying asset c. In your code it assumes that each asset has a contract for each expiration N13, M13 and Z13. In reality, each asset is going to have a unique range of expirations. So a and b might have an expirarition on N13. B and c have Z13, finally a and c share M13. So I am thinking that using the above code is going to have trouble aligning the data. Right?

Comment: @BrandonOgle No it should align it (and put NaNs where data isn't present).

Comment: @BrandonOgle or are you suggesting there is some kind of many-to-many relation?

Comment: No, just that they contracts have expirations that aren't uniform across every one of the underlying commodities. I was hoping I would just get NaNs. I am going try again, but I will likely be back for help :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok this seemed to work.

```
commodities = {}
columns = 'open', 'high', 'low', 'settle', 'volume', 'interest', 'delivery' #Contract fields
path = os.getcwdu()+'/Futures_Contracts/' #Futures Path
for sym in os.listdir(path):
    if sym[0] != '.': #Weed out hidden files
        i = 0
        c_expirations = {}
        for contract in os.listdir(path + sym):
            expiry = (contract[:-4][-1].encode('ascii', 'ignore') + contract[:-4][:-1][-2:].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
            c_expirations[expiry] = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(path + sym + '/' + contract, index_col=0, parse_dates = True, names = columns)
        commodities[sym] = pd.concat(c_expirations, axis =1)
df_data = pd.concat(commodities, axis=1)
df_data.columns.names = 'asset', 'expiry', 'data'
```

and a look at what it prints out

```
print df_data


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1568 entries, 2007-04-16 00:00:00 to 2013-06-17 00:00:00
Columns: 1197 entries, (CC2, H14, open) to (ZW, Z13, delivery)
dtypes: float64(1197)
```

Really just came down to tinkering with Andy's advice, and applying it large scale

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help! Now I need to think long and hard about how to proceed :(