# iteratively read (tsv) file for Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, eye-tracking

I have some experimental data which looks like this - http://paste2.org/YzJL4e1b (too long to post here). The blocks which are separated by field name lines are different trials of the same experiment - I would like to read everything in a pandas dataframe but have it bin together certain trials (for instance 0,1,6,7 taken together - and 2,3,4,5 taken together in another group). This is because different trials have slightly different conditions and I would like to analyze the results difference between these conditions. I have a list of numbers for different conditions from another file.

Currently I am doing this:

```
tracker_data = pd.DataFrame
tracker_data = tracker_data.from_csv(bhpath+i+'_wmet.tsv', sep='\t', header=4)
tracker_data['GazePointXLeft'] = tracker_data['GazePointXLeft'].astype(np.float64)
```

but this of course just reads everything in one go (including the field name lines) - it would be great if I could nest the blocks somehow which allows me to easily access them via numeric indices...

Do you have any ideas how I could best do this?

Comment: Ahh, I'm really close I think.  @TheCymera, is the data you uploaded exactly how it is on your machine?  How are the last few columns in the first row handled where there's missing data?  Are they just tabs?

Comment: yes, I took the content via copy/paste from leafpad (my text basic editor). The last columns don't really bother me though - it'S the selective binning I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) rather than `from_csv`*:

```
tracker_data = pd.read_csv(bhpath+i+'_wmet.tsv', sep='\t', header=4)
```

If you want to join a list of DataFrames like this you could use concat:

```
trackers = (pd.read_csv(bhpath+i+'_wmet.tsv', sep='\t', header=4) for i in range(?))
df = pd.concat(trackers)
```

* *which I think is deprecated.*

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I want to do - these blocks are all in one file - not different files as our code suggests.

Comment: @TheChymera apologies, I misread. I'm not quite sure what you're after. Are you asking for a read csv which only reads in certain columns?

Comment: no, I am asking for a way to read the entire .tsv file (without the separating string-containing rows) but in such a way that I can call the blocks separated by these rows via indexes. Somethink like a 3d-dataframe maybe?

Comment: @TheChymera you're looking for a MultiIndex... will flesh out an answer tomorrow :)

Comment: @TheChymera related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178263/commodity-futures-hierarchical-data-structure

Answer (score 0):

I haven't quite got it working, but I think that's because of how I copy/pasted the data.  Try this, let me know if it doesn't work.

Using some inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020935/splitting-one-file-into-two-files-with-python)

```
pat = "TimeStamp\tGazePointXLeft\tGazePointYLeft\tValidityLeft\tGazePointXRight\tGazePointYRight\tValidityRight\tGazePointX\tGazePointY\tEvent\n"
with open('rec.txt') as infile:
    header, names, tail = infile.read().partition(pat)

names = names.split()  # get rid of the tabs here
all_data = tail.split(pat)
res = [pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), sep='\t', names=names) for x in all_data]
```

We read in the whole file so this won't work for huge files, and then partition it based on the known line giving the column names.  `tail` is just a string with the rest of the data so we can split that, again based on the names.  There may be a better way than using StringIO, but this should work.

I'm note sure how you want to join the separate blocks together, but this leaves them as a list.  You can concat from there however you desire.

For larger files you might want to write a generator to read until you hit the column names and write a new file until you hit them again.  Then read those in separately using something like Andy's answer.

A separate question from how to work with the multiple blocks.  Assuming you've got the list of `Dataframe`s, which I've called `res`, you can use pandas' [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#concatenating-objects) to join them together into a single DataFrame with a MultiIndex (also see the link Andy posted).

```
In [122]: df = pd.concat(res, axis=1, keys=['a', 'b', 'c'])  # Use whatever makes sense for the keys

In [123]: df.xs('TimeStamp', level=1, axis=1)
Out[123]: 
     a    b    c
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  3.3  3.3  3.3
3  6.6  6.6  6.6
```

Comment: I tried using the code, but the third line doesn't seem to be working - header, names, tail = infile.read().partition(pat) writes all the data in header while names and tail are empty.

Comment: Play around with pat.  To be sure that you get exactly what you need try `f = open('rec.txt')` and the `pat = f.read()` 4 or 5 times.  `f.read()` will read one line at a time so you have to get rid of the header.  Once you have `pat` assigned to the correct string, try again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it iteratively. very very iteratively. Nothing else seems to work.

```
pat = 'TimeStamp    GazePointXLeft  GazePointYLeft  ValidityLeft    GazePointXRight GazePointYRight ValidityRight   GazePointX  GazePointY  Event'
with open(bhpath+fileid+'_wmet.tsv') as infile:
    eye_data = infile.read().split(pat)
    eye_data = [trial.split('\r\n') for trial in eye_data] # split at '\r'
    for idx, trial in enumerate(eye_data):
        trial = [row.split('\t') for row in trial]
        eye_data[idx] = trial
```